# Add Entries to the Context Menu

Tags: context-menu

In Chrome and Gnome Terminal, I want to add context menu entries to search Youtube. Any pointers as to how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding sections describing desktop actions to the launcher of the application. For example, the launcher of the Google Chrome application contains a few such sections to add the "New Window" and "New Incognito Window" sections, like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
...
Actions=new-window;new-private-window

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=New Incognito Window
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito
```

By adding your own `[Desktop action ...]` sections, you can add additional right-click options or modify the existing ones.

Copy the launcher to your `~/.local/share/applications` if you are the only user needing the additional right-click items. You can then copy and customize the launcher as a normal user.

If you wish to make the change available systemwide, then modify a copy of the launcher in `/usr/local/share/applications`. You need to create the folder as it does not exist by default in Ubuntu. You could also edit the installed launcher directly, but it may be overwritten on a subsequent update. You need root permissions to make these system wide changes.

Comment: Per the Desktop Entries Specification (https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html), "It is not valid to have an action group for an action identifier not mentioned in the `Actions` key." So for instance here, you would also need, in the main `[Desktop Entry]` group, a line with at least `Actions=new-window;new-private-window`

Comment: @rakslice, thanks for the comment. That is an omission that I will correct in the answer